# iOS <-> PHP encryption

Tags: php, iphone, ios, encryption

I am using this encyption function in my php code:

```
function _encrypt($key,$string){
$string = ' '.$string.' ';
return  base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key)
, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
    }

function _decrypt($key,$encrypted){
    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key),
    base64_decode($encrypted),
    MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
}
```

I would like to know the iOS equivalent functions that might support this on the iPhone's side to negotiate with the server.

Thanks!

Comment: MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is pretty non-standard. Use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 if you tried to use AES. Using a 256 bit cipher with a 128 bit key is a bit non-sensical anyway.

Comment: I don't mind moving on to 128, could you please present any iOS code for that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's still relevant but I created a git project which enables you to send an NSDictionary, encrypted or unencrypted from iOS to PHP

Check it out: [Github: JNKTransmitter](https://github.com/JNK/JNKTransmitter)